# How accurate is TTimer?

Tags: delphi

When I set the `TTimer` interval to `1`, does it in reality execute the code every 1 millisecond or is it like every 20 milliseconds or something?

I am asking this question because I know that the Windows API `Sleep()` function is not accurate, so I want to know if it is the same for `TTimer`.

Comment: TTimer wraps SetTimer, the UI timer. What's missing is why you ask the question.

Comment: *Because a timer's accuracy depends on the system clock rate and how often the application retrieves messages from the message queue, the time-out value is only approximate.* ([`Source`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644900%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Comment: On many systems the precision of TTimer is 40 ms, so it cannot be used for precision work. You can use the multimedia timers in mmsystem or if you have a newer delphi you can use the debug timers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The standard VCL TTimer component is a wrapper for the Windows API timer functions SetTimer and KillTimer. TTimer simplifies the processing of the WM_TIMER messages by converting them into OnTimer events. A timer based on WM_TIMER message processing cannot provide a resolution better than 10 milliseconds.

[Source: Sergworks](https://sergworks.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/a-better-timer-for-a-delphi-programmer/)